# How to connect to Oracle using JRuby & JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jruby

First approach: bare metal

```
require 'java'
require 'rubygems'
require "c:/ruby/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ojdbc14.jar"  # should be redundant, but tried it anyway
odriver = Java::JavaClass.for_name("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
puts odriver.java_class
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:mydb"
puts "About to connect..."
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, "myuser", "mypassword");
if con
    puts " connection good"
else
    puts " connection failed"
end
```

The result of the above is:

```
sqltest.rb:4: cannot load Java class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver (NameError)
```

Second approach: Active Record

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'ActiveRecord-JDBC'
require 'jdbc_adapter'
require 'active_record'
require 'active_record/version'
require "c:/ruby/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ojdbc14.jar"  # should be redundant...

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   :adapter => 'jdbc',
   :driver => 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
   :url => 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:mydb',
   :username=>'myuser',
   :password=>'mypassword'
 )
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
```

The result of this is:

```
C:/ruby/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-0.9.1/lib/active_recordconnection_adapters/jdbc_adapter.rb:330:in `initialize': 
The driver encountered an error: cannot load Java class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver (RuntimeError)
```

Essentially the same error no matter how I go about it.

I'm using JRuby 1.2.0 and I have ojdbc14.jar in my JRuby lib directory

Gems:

- ActiveRecord-JDBC (0.5)
- activerecord-jdbc-adapter (0.9.1)
- activerecord (2.2.2)

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: I'll be interested to see if SO can beat the ruby forum (http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/184414)

Comment: Originally posted to Nabble http://www.nabble.com/Having-problems-accessing-Oracle-td23070394.html
I guess they get propigated to Ruby Forum somehow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that my ojdbc14.jar file was corrupt.

Further, the jar file MUST be in the jruby/lib directory.  Simply having it on the classpath does not work.

Comment: appears these days having it in the (jruby specific) CLASSPATH environment variable is also enough, but just doing a require 'ojdbc14.jar' is not.

Comment: also appears that these days you just need to require the jar, it doesn't have to be in the lib dir anymore (1.6.0RC2)

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'java'

# This require doesn't load the jdbc driver jar into the system class path
require "c:/ruby/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ojdbc14.jar" 

# 2 ways you can load the class (There are probably more)

# 1 ruby syntax for java class name
Java::OracleJdbcDriver::OracleDriver

# 2 Use the thread context class loader
java.lang.Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", true, java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader)


url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:mydb"
puts "About to connect..."
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, "myuser", "mypassword");
if con
    puts " connection good"
else
    puts " connection failed"
end
```

Comment: I'm using your example now, but what I don't understand is how I would run commands. Can you please get back to me on that?

Answer (score 3):

and then to use it after creation:

```
b = con.create_statement
rs=b.execute_query(“select BANNER from SYS.V_$VERSION”)
while(rs.next())
  p rs.getObject(1) # get first column
end
rs.close

and how to deal with oracle timestamps (if column 3 is a timestamp, for example):

>> rs.getObject(3).timestamp_value.to_string
=> “1970-01-01 00:00:01.0″
>> Date.parse(rs.getObject(3).timestamp_value.to_string)
# or you can use time, like
>> as_ruby_time= Date.parse(rs.getObject(3).timestamp_value.to_string).to_time # 1.9 has this method
# or
>> as_ruby_time = Time.at(0) + rs.getObject(3).timestamp_value.get_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the Oracle client installed? you probably need at least the jdbc driver files from the client

Comment: Yes, but I did not think it would be required with this "thin" connection type.

Comment: yeah the jar is typically enough.