# NameError: cannot load jdbc.OracleDriver - jrubyNameError

Tags: java, ruby, jdbc, jruby

I have a class that imports OracleDriver

```
 require 'java'    
 java_import 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'   <= Get error here
```

I am getting :

```
NameError: cannot load Java class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
         for_name at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:1204
  get_proxy_class at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:34
      java_import at /home/pboob/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:46
```

This was working fine before but I thing something messed up in the env.

The was I am invoking the script is jruby --1.9 .. but from the stack trace it seems like it is picking up jruby-1.6.4 ?

Any ideas how I should debug this and what is happening ?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're requiring the oracle JDBC drive.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755207/how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-jruby-jdbc).

Comment: The problem got resolved after I copied ojdbc14.jar to lib in jruby. I wonder what changed in my env though :) since it worked before ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem got resolved after I copied ojdbc14.jar to lib in jruby.