# Ruby on Rails - rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rake, aptana

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and am having a problem. I have installed Aptana RadRails 2. I have created a project using the Oracle option. I have Oracle Express installed on my PC.

I then generated some scaffolding, which executed successfully.

I then selected my project -> Rake ->db -> migrate.

The following error message appeared:

```
e:1 warning: already initialized constant RUBY_PLATFORM
(in C:/Users/sean_/My Documents/Aptana RadRails Workspace/comics_catalog)
rake aborted!
The driver encountered an error: cannot load Java class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this problem?

Thanks, Sean

Comment: maybe this one can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755207/how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-jruby-jdbc, but it is hard to troubleshot with information that you provided, it could be due to configuration or lacking of required dependencies or external binaries, to me rake just try to run it but due to issues mentioned, it gets the error and as result it gets aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Afro. I moved my jdbc.jar file to the location suggested in the link you provide me with. And yes, it worked. Thank you for yo